# UIImage grayscale thresholding

Tags: ios

I want to threshold a grayscale UIImage. What's the easiest way to do this?

I think I have to get the bitmap of the UIImage and then compare it to some value and then set it to either 0/255. How to get the bitmap?

Comment: Do you want bitmap from UIImage ?

Comment: Is this an image processing question or an iOS question?

Comment: I guess what I meant was, where are you stuck? Do you need help getting an array of pixels from a UIImage? Do you not know the formula for RGB to Grayscale? Need help converting back to UIImage?

Comment: I converted RGB to grayscale...now I want to convert it to black and white by thresholding.